# New user templates for Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs

In Windows Server, is there a way to have certain tasks be performed ever time a new user is created? Basically, I would like a way to change the default groups and create a windows share every time a user is created.

I am using SBS 2011 Essentials, but whatever works in 2008 R2 should most likely work in SBS 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could whip something up with Powershell that would do that for you.  Take a look on the [Scripting Repository](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849) first though, someone else has probably done this already.